# How can I alter a primary key constraint using SQL syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a table that is missing a column in its primary key constraint.  Instead of editing it through SQL Server, I want to put this in a script to add it as part of our update scripts.

What syntax can I use to do this? Must I drop and recreate the key constraint?

Comment: AFAIK yes, you need to drop and recreate the PK constraint. I don't recall any command to add a column to an already-existing PK/FK constraint.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Yes. The only way would be to drop the constraint with an Alter table then recreate it.

```
ALTER TABLE <Table_Name>
DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>

ALTER TABLE <Table_Name>
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> PRIMARY KEY (<Column1>,<Column2>)
```

Comment: If you don't know the primary key constraint name, use query found here to look it up (or look up and drop all at once). [http://stackoverflow.com/a/13948609/945875](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13948609/945875)

Comment: if it wasn't clear, or anyone else makes the same mistake, the constraint name can't go in quotes `alter table PatientsInfo
drop constraint PK__Patients__1CBB51380A338187` is working here

Comment: For those of you, not knowing the constraint name: ALTER TABLE `db`.`table`
  DROP PRIMARY KEY,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id1`, `id2`);

Comment: ALTER TABLE db.table DROP PRIMARY KEY is for MySQL. (Not MSSQL.)

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of trouble is you execute "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_TABLE on TABLE (<Column1>,<Column2>)" **BEFORE** you drop the old constraint.  This will help make sure the create constraint statement at the end will work.

Answer (score 26):

`PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT` cannot be altered, you may only drop it and create again. For big datasets it can cause a long run time and thus - table inavailability.

Answer (score 4):

Performance wise there is no point to keep non clustered indexes during this as they will get re-updated on drop and create.
If it is a big data set you should consider renaming the table (if possible , any security settings on it?), re-creating an empty table with the correct keys migrate all data there.
You have to make sure you have enough space for this.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I want to add a column  to a Primary key  (column4).
I used this script to add column4

```
ALTER TABLE TableA
DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA]

ALTER TABLE TableA
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA] PRIMARY KEY (
    [column1] ASC,
    [column2] ASC, 
    [column3] ASC,
    [column4] ASC
)
```

Answer (score 3):

**PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT** can only be drop and then create again.
For example in MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (Column1,Column2);
```

Answer (score -4):

you can rename constraint objects using sp_rename (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8712921/2813621))

for example:

```
EXEC sp_rename N'schema.MyIOldConstraint', N'MyNewConstraint'
```

Comment: The question was how to change the constraint, i.e. ADD a column, not how to rename.