# how to insert the same id from 1st table to the 2nd table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm here again, but today i just wanted to ask how to insert the current id of the user to another table. I mean the user has already an ID in the first one. and I want to insert the exact same Id in 2nd table.

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$id=$_POST['P_Id'];
$date=$_POST['appdate'];
$time=$_POST['apptime'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$contact=$_POST['contact'];
$service=$_POST['service'];
$status = "pending";
$dentist= "Dr. Adrian Romero";
$msg= "Appointment Sucessfully Inserted ";
$update= mysql_query("INSERT INTO appointments (P_Id,LasName,FirstName,contact,appdate,apptime,service,status) values ('$id','$date','$time','$dentist','$fname','$lname','$contact','$service','$status')" );
$id=mysql_insert_id();
if($update)
{
echo "<script> alert('Thank you For Requesting an appointment. please wait for the administrator s response after 24 hrs')</script>";
header('Location:Patient.php');
}
else
{
$msge= mysql_error();
$errormsg="Something went wrong, Try again!";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$errormsg');</script>";
}
```

plus. I don't really Understand the function of mysql_insert_id(); please help thank you have a good day! :D

Comment: What's not working ?

Comment: You shouldn't use any mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since php 5.5 and completely removed in php 7.0

Comment: @Adrian Romero mysql_insert_id — Get the ID generated in the last query [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php]. Its will give you last insert id.

Comment: @AlokPatel it just goes to else. and it does nothing.but when i remove the variable $id and P_Id in the column  inside the query it returns 0

Comment: But i suggest not to use mysql_*. because It was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead of mysql_* , MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: @Adrian Romero The reason behind you didn't give auto increment to `p_id`.

Comment: check these link [http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp] [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761570/how-can-i-alter-a-primary-key-constraint-using-sql-syntax]. These will give you information how to alter/ create primary key constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic terminology in the mysql and as well as mysqli is the `mysqli_insert_id`

Your Insert Statement is Entirely Wrong . You have Inserted Random Values in the Insert Statement. Try using the code below that i have mentioned.

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$id=$_POST['P_Id'];
$date=$_POST['appdate'];
$time=$_POST['apptime'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$contact=$_POST['contact'];
$service=$_POST['service'];
$status = "pending";
$dentist= "Dr. Adrian Romero";
$msg= "Appointment Sucessfully Inserted ";
$query ="INSERT INTO `appointments` (`P_Id`,`LasName`,`FirstName`,`contact`,`appdate`,`apptime`,`service`,`status`) VALUES ('".$id."','".$lname."','".$fname."','".$contact."','".$date."','".$time."','".$service."','".$status."')";
$update= mysql_query($query);
$id=mysql_insert_id();
if($id)
{
echo "<script> alert('Thank you For Requesting an appointment. please wait for the administrator s response after 24 hrs')</script>";
header('Location:Patient.php');
}
else
{
$msge= mysql_error();
$errormsg="Something went wrong, Try again!";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$errormsg');</script>";
}
?>
```

As of now the `mysql.*` has been depreciated use of `mysqli.*` is preferred.

mysqli_insert_id — Returns the auto generated id used in the last query

The `mysqli_insert_id()` function returns the ID generated by a query on a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this function will return zero.

> **Note:**
>   Performing an INSERT or UPDATE statement using the LAST_INSERT_ID() function will also modify the value returned by the mysqli_insert_id() function.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age)
VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");

// Print auto-generated id
echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id($con);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

If you want to get the last inserted id in `mysqli.*` you have to pass the `$con- connection variable` for further purpose.

Comment: @Adrian Romero . If you have obtained the solution let me know. If you find it useful +1 since this is a very common error that all the developers make hence it may be useful for the rest of them.