# Cannot add primary key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a table and add a constraint with `alter table` but it's not working:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
cust_id NUMBER(3),
cust_name VARCHAR2(3),
phone_no NUMBER(10)
);

ALTER  TABLE  customer
ADD  CONSTRAINT  pk_customer
PRIMARY  KEY  (cust_id);
```

This is the error:

> near "CONSTRAINT": syntax error

What did I do wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859353/alter-table-to-add-a-composite-primary-key or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761570/how-can-i-alter-a-primary-key-constraint-using-sql-syntax

Comment: I think you need to delete the text  ' CONSTRAINT  pk_customer'. If you are new with MySQL, probably you find [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-primary-key/) useful.

Comment: You need to show us the full error message. Also I think you made a mistake in the tags. It should be [tag:mysql] instead of [tag:mysqli]

Comment: This is Oracle database. Why are you using mysqli?

Comment: @TheImpaler Why would you say it is Oracle? It was a mistake in the tags... see my comment above.

Comment: @Dharman Because of `VARCHAR2`... and because it works fine in Oracle 12c.

Comment: Good catch, I missed that.

Comment: Also `NUMBER` is an Oracle data type, not recognized by MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

for `mysql` try with

```
ALTER TABLE customer
ADD PRIMARY KEY(cust_id);
```

or directly from `CREATE TABLE`

Attention! : compatible fields types within `mysql`

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    cust_id NUMBER(3),
    cust_name VARCHAR2(3),
    phone_no NUMBER(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(cust_id)
);
```

Comment: Your answer also contains `VARCHAR2` from Oracle DB. You might want to take this into consideration.

Comment: @Dharman, yes just copy his field as were designed. The main question was about PK and assumed that first query with `CREATE TABLE` was working before issue `ALTER`.(assuming just a typo). If not then is another story ...

Comment: @Dharman also even `NUMBER(10)` is not a valid type within `mysql` but here was for him to check.

Answer (score 0):

Your statements work well... in Oracle database (12c1 at least).

In order for your query to work in **MySQL**, you need to change the data types.  (see  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/944440/1)). For example:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
cust_id DECIMAL(3), -- changed here
cust_name VARCHAR(3), -- changed here
phone_no DECIMAL(10) -- changed here
);

ALTER  TABLE  customer
ADD  CONSTRAINT  pk_customer
PRIMARY  KEY  (cust_id);
```

Comment: Sorry for reply late, I use https://jsfiddle.net/(mysql online) for the code above and get the error

Comment: That would be correct, since `VARCHAR2` and `NUMBER` are **not valid** column types in MySQL.

Comment: I was testing by replace all, just keep cust_id with INT, like this:
 `CREATE TABLE customer
(
cust_id INT
);

ALTER  TABLE  customer
ADD  CONSTRAINT  pk_customer
PRIMARY  KEY  (cust_id);` but it still get the same error

Comment: Thanks, It works, but in this website (https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-sql-online), your code get the error, can u explain why, I don't get it

Comment: OK, that site is for SQLite only, not MySQL. Totally different database engine.