# Rename database constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have to rename constraints in database. Current DB is created by the following script (sample, part):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
    [Column1] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) NOT NULL,
    ...
```

Now I need to rename default constraint attached to `[Column1]`.
How is it possible to do?

Comment: Hint: find out the defaults name...

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server rename a constraint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712875/sql-server-rename-a-constraint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mitch suggests, you will need to find the actual name of the automatically generated default. Assuming there is only one default on the table:

```
declare @Name nvarchar(50);
select @Name = name from sys.default_constraints 
  where parent_object_id = Object_Id('dbo.table1');
exec sp_rename @Name, 'NewConstraintName';
```

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can rename constraints, there are two ways

- drop the current constraint and recreate them ( its easy but obviously its not possible all time)
- you can use stored procedure sp_rename

Like this

```
exec sp_rename ‘PK_1231’,
'PK_MyTableName',
'OBJECT';
```

for more information please refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx
Section "Renaming constraints"