# H2 database: is it possible to rename a constraint?

Tags: sql, constraints, h2

Is there a way to rename a constraint in H2 database?

Same question as this one: [SQL Server rename a constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712875/sql-server-rename-a-constraint), but for H2 database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mr Thomas Muellers's answer was correct at the time, but H2 has improved, since. It now allows renaming a constraint:

[ALTER TABLE RENAME CONSTRAINT](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#alter_table_rename_constraint)

(since version 1.4.192)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not, there is no SQL statement in [the grammar of H2](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html) that can do it.

So you would need to create a new constraint and drop the old one.

Comment: Hmm, at this time, the grammar you link to shows information for the commands ALTER INDEX RENAME as an option; but not foreign key constraints.