# How to change default constraint_name in sql?

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

How do i change change/edit the constraint_name that is being displayed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server rename a constraint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712875/sql-server-rename-a-constraint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint we need to rename is `DF__oldername__c1__7C8480AE`. Now we need to drop the constraint and then add the new one as there's no way to simply alter the constraint in-place. We do that using:

```
ALTER TABLE Tablename DROP CONSTRAINT DF__oldername__c1__7C8480AE;
ALTER TABLE Tablename ADD CONSTRAINT DF__newname__c1
DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() FOR c1;
```

and we are done.